# c++: 'WiFiClient' does not name a type

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

Here is some simple c++ source code: https://github.com/kenpeter/test_cpp_lib

I compiled it in arduino and I got "'WiFiClient' does not name a type". Basically what I want to do is define a variable "client" in run_mode.cpp, then I want to use it in mqtt.cpp.

test_cpp_lib.ino

```
#include <WiFiClient.h>;
#include "run_mode.h";
#include "mqtt.h";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("test");
  delay(2000);
}
```

mqtt.cpp

```
extern WiFiClient client;

// do something with client
```

run_mode.cpp

```
WiFiClient client;
```

run_mode.h

```
extern WiFiClient client;
```

mqtt.h is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WiFiClient is not a built-in type like int or char. It's a class that must be defined (usually in a header file) before you can create an instance of it. In your example code, there is no such definition, but you are trying to instantiate WiFiClient in run_mode.cpp. Perhaps run_mode.cpp must include WiFiClient.h.

By the way, you must not add semicolons at the end of an #include directive.